# Detect change of UILabel's text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have a time that repeats itself every .1 seconds (I do this because I need to constantly look for a change on the website's text I am pulling from). My problem is that I need to be able to tell when the text changes from one word to another. So when the user open the app and let's say the text is displaying one song title but then it changes to a different one, Where it changes, I need to be able to detect it and preform an action.

Also it has to be when the app first loads it will not preform the action but when the text changes it will display it(It has to be this because I am pulling song titles). So I need to be able to change the duration of each song, but if a song is playing and they open the app in the middle of it, the duration will be mixed up. so I have two labels, one that shows text and another that shows the time. When the app first loads up, I want it to display nothing until the text in the song title changes, then pulls the duration from a if statement (below). It might be a little confusing but ask any question you need and I will try to explain.

Here is my code for pulling from the website and anything else that might help:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(recentTracksText) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)recentTracksText {

    textForBlog = [webViewForRecents stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('current_song').textContent;"];

    self.strippedTextForBlog = [self stringByStrippingHTMLFromString:textForBlog];

    continuousLabel.text = self.strippedTextForBlog;

}

if ([continuousLabel.text isEqual: @"Lady Gaga - Gypsy"]) {
            imageView1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lady Gaga - Gypsy.jpg"];
            imageView.hidden = YES;
            [self.view insertSubview:toolbar belowSubview:imageView];
            [toolbar insertSubview:darkView belowSubview:imageView];
            [self.view insertSubview:backgroundImage belowSubview:toolbar];
            if([darkView.subviews containsObject:continuousLabel]) {

            } else{
                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0);
                dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                    [darkView addSubview:Label];
                    [Label setText:@"1:30"];
                    [darkView addSubview:continuousLabel];
                });
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE**

```
-(void)recentTracksText {

    textForBlog = [webViewForRecents stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('current_song').textContent;"];

    self.strippedTextForBlog = [self stringByStrippingHTMLFromString:textForBlog];
    if (![self.strippedTextForBlog isEqualToString:continuousLabel.text])// this does not find when the text changes {
        [self.pLabel setHidden:NO];
        [self.pLabel setProgress:1  
                          timing:TPPropertyAnimationTimingEaseOut
                        duration:150.0
                           delay:0.0];  //This does not go smoothy.
    // this does not 
    }  
    continuousLabel.text = self.strippedTextForBlog;
}
```

Comment: You can register for notification when the value changes - see this stack overflow answer for a concise example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14872086/189804 - seems like you could watch for changes on continuousLabel.text?

Comment: @AdamEberbach I tried this in the past but because it fires every .1 seconds it say the text changes every .1 second

Comment: If you set it every time it does. How about setting only when different?

Comment: How would I go about that?

Comment: `if (![self.strippedTextForBlog isEqualToString:continuousLabel.text])` should work, if it isn't working the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Was going to say what Blue Gene said...

Comment: And btw, The reason the animation does not go smoothly is because you need to change `TPPropertyAnimationTimingEaseOut` to `TPPropertyAnimationTimingLinear`

Comment: The 'self.strippedTextForBlog' is just the text I am pulling from the website and continuousLabel.text is showing it.

Comment: Please set a breakpoint or `NSLog` both the `self.strippedTextForBlog` and `continuousLabel.text` to see if they match.

Comment: so you pull 600 times per minute? sounds like an app to drain battery…

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have no other way (In my knowledge) because when the text changes on the website, I need it to change on the app right away

Comment: if I was the website owner, I'd block any connection from your app.

Comment: @vikingosegundo I actually am the website owner. The app is fine on battery, if you know a better way then feel free to share

Comment: if you run the server, install a socket based gateway where your app can register.

Comment: poling is always the worst solution and should be only the very last option.

Comment: @vikingosegundo In my situation, it is the only way I know how.

Comment: if you plan to publish your app, you should think about it. just imagine it becomes popular and maybe 100 users use it at the same time. that would be 60,000 request per minute. that is a lot and would need a quite expensive server setup.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Yes but do understand that it is only the text from a online player.

Comment: it is not the amount of data that should worry you, but the number of request your server has to handle.

Comment: @vikingosegundo But it is not relying on the sever to begin with, it is all within the app

Comment: but your app will do 600 request per minute, right? so it doesn't matter what your app does with the response. the request do occur and you will very likely have some trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already have the `NSTimer` that fires each 0.1 seconds, so you just have to check if the text wasn't changed.

```
-(void)recentTracksText {

    textForBlog = [webViewForRecents stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('current_song').textContent;"];

    self.strippedTextForBlog = [self stringByStrippingHTMLFromString:textForBlog];

    if (![self.self.strippedTextForBlog isEqualToString:continuousLabel.text]) {
    //The text isn't the same. Do something.
    }

    continuousLabel.text = self.strippedTextForBlog;

}
```

Comment: The problem is then my action will preform every .1 seconds now. Not only that but it doesn't stop it when they first open the app in the middle of a song.

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw You said your action is already preforming every .1 seconds? your NSTimer fires every 0.1 seconds, just check if the text was changed.

Comment: This almost works but I need it not to work when the app first loads up and then when the text changes display the Label

Comment: Do you mean when the label isn't set yet? (When the app loads?) try  `if (![self.self.strippedTextForBlog isEqualToString:continuousLabel.text] && !continuousLabel.hidden)`

Answer (score 2):

[Use Key-value observing if you want to observe the property directly](http://nshipster.com/key-value-observing/)

```
[continuousLabel addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"text"
            options:0
            context:NULL];

Make sure you implement the observing method

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
   // Insert your code here to deal with the change.
}
```

and a little bit of ARC management to taste:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc %@", [self class]);
    if (continuousLabel) {
        [continuousLabel removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text"];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is it is telling me the text is changing every .1 second because thats what it is pulling at

Comment: pulling should not be needed with KVO

Comment: @vikingosegundo It is needed because I need to pull the text from a website with the changing text.

Comment: KVO only fires if there is a change to the text which is what you said you wanted.

Comment: `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];`